# How can I take my Keynote presentations Database from iCloud?

Tags: ipad

How can I restore my Keynote database from iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Sign into https://icloud.com on a web browser and download them to your computer and then sync them with iTunes.

- Delete the Keynote app (if you have to and have exported all presentations to the computer or can let them be deleted)
- Go to settings -> iCloud -> iCloud Documents and be sure to turn it on and keynote on
- Connect to WiFi or allow cellular data for iCloud Data
- Install the Keynote app
- Open it and wait for the data to flow down to the device